# Is lowering my voice during salat riya?

Tags: hadith, salat, sharia, shirk, kufr

Sometimes my family members walk in on me praying and my voice automatically becomes more quiet but I really don’t know why. It’s not like I’m trying to do my prayer for them but it automatically happens. Is this riya or shirk? I’m really worried because it happens every time somebody walks in. Are those prayers valid?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Bismillah Hir Rahmaan Nir Raheem**

**As Salaamu 3laykum,**

I hope you are doing well. In this case I think there are three possibilities. One would be you are doing it show off that how quiet you are praying and how others will look at you praying. The second possibility is that you lower your voice so that others do not get disturbed if they are doing other things. The third possibility is that you think your voice / recitation is not good and people will not like it.

**Possibility #1& #3**

If its due to showing off then please stop doing the action because each action is due to what what we intend to do with it. Please look at the following evidences.

Quran

> Indeed, the hypocrites [think to] deceive Allah , but He is deceiving them. And when they stand for prayer, they stand lazily, **showing** [themselves to] the people and not remembering ALLAAH except a little ([Surah 4 verse 142](https://quran.com/8/47?font=indopak))

Hadith

> The Prophet (Peace and Blessings Be Upon Him) said, "The rewards (of deeds) are according to the intention, and everybody will get the reward for what he has **intended**. So whoever emigrated for ALLAAH and His Apostle's sake, his emigration was for ALLAAH and His Apostle; and whoever emigrated for worldly benefits, or to marry a woman, then his emigration was for the thing for what he emigrated for. ([Bukhari](https://sunnah.com/bukhari:5070))

**Possibility #2**

If it is due to you just wanting to be kind and not disturb anyone with a loud recitation then that is a good thing. Always keep a middle ground in matters. Never go into extremes. Below are some evidences to show actions whether through words or actions should always be done with kindness.

Quran

> Or that He would not seize them gradually [in a state of dread]? But indeed, your Lord is **Kind** and Merciful. ([Surah 4 verse 47](https://quran.com/16/47?font=indopak))

Hadith

> The Messenger of ALLAAH (Peace and Blessings Be Upon Him) said: ALLAAH is Kind and loves **kindness**, and He rewards for kindness in a way that He does not reward for harshness.

**Conclusion**

Inshaa ALLAAH I would ask yourself why you do each action and introspect into your life so that you make sure that each action is done for ALLAAH (Subhanahu Wa Ta3la) and His happiness and love.

**Have a Nice Day!**

**Note #1:** If you downvote my answer, please be courteous and say why you downvoted in a comment below.

**Note #2:** This is my own personal answer that I have derived from what I have researched.

Comment: Thanks, you explained it well, I’m still not sure why I exactly I do it but I’m just gonna try to not change the way I pray when someone walks in

Comment: As Salaamu 3laykum, you are most welcome. Inshaa ALLAAH that's good. I will modify my answer to add that maybe you don't want people to listen to your voice because you don't think you have a good voice. If that is the case don't worry as that falls under point one in my answer. Have a good day!